# How to start VMware virtual machine guests automatically after booting up?

Tags: windows-7, vmware

We have a Windwos 7 host with VmWare 8 installed. After the Win 7 machine boots up, selected virtual machines should boot as well automatically. With automatically I mean, that no one has to login or do something manual at the host.

How can we do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Workstation 8, there is an "Autostart VMs" feature. On my copy, you click on the "Shared VMs" folder, then the right pane will have a item that says: "Manage AutoStart VMs"

Answer (score 10):

kbyrd's answer only works with shared vm's. Ja5087's answer works, but there is another way that is cross platform.  I provide this answer because I was looking for the same answer today and did not come across a single post will all the information.

This answer allows starting a vm in the background if you so choose.

Create a script with the following command:

`vmrun -T {ws|server|player|...} [-vp virtualMachinePassword] [-gu guestUser] [-gp guestPassword] start "path to vmx file" [nogui]`

**-vp** is the virtualMachinePassword for encrypted machines

**-gu** is the guest user to sign in with and **-gp** is the guest user password if you want to autologin and it is not set in the vm config.

**nogui** starts the vm in the background

To prevent failure of startup due to vmware dialogs, edit the .vmx file and add the following options to auto answer any vmware dialogs:

`uuid.action = "keep"` OR `uuid.action = "create"`

`msg.autoAnswer = "TRUE"`

For the uuid.action, this answers the question when you start the vm after moving or copying to a new location.  **keep** is the equivalent of "I Moved It", **create** is the equivalent of "I Copied It".

Answer (score 2):

Put a shortcut to the vm file in the startup folder should work I think.

Comment: Thanks! Gues this means I have to login right?

Comment: If you have the settings set to that yes.